# Default Order of Case Statement, for use in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm building a report in SSRS. I have values from a DB column populating the row headings in a matrix in the report. These are display fine. The problem is that they display alphabetically and i don't know how to have them display in an order i have defined.

The SQL query looks like:

```
 CASE   
   WHEN Age >= 0 AND Age <3 THEN 'Newborn 0-3 Months'
   WHEN Age > 3 AND Age <= 12 THEN 'Infant 3-12 Months'
   When Age > 12 THEN 'Child'
   ELSE 'Invalid Age'
 END AS AgeGroup
```

Which works. But in my report it displays the columns so 'Child' displays before 'Infant' and so on.

Is there a way i can define the order? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need an order by clause in your query, can you post the full query syntax please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a second case statement to use in the ordering:

```
CASE   
   WHEN Age >= 0 AND Age <3 THEN 10
   WHEN Age > 3 AND Age <= 12 THEN 20
   When Age > 12 THEN 30
   ELSE 40 -- or 0, perhaps
END AS AgeGroupOrder
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. I had to add a hidden column in my SSRS report which forced the columns to display in the order defined by 'AgeGroupOrder'. Thanks a lot!